# Can upgrading Windows Server R2 Standard to Windows Server R2 Enterprise affect configurations of installed SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I try searching anywhere in other sites and I can't find a good answer to my question maybe I just search here and find the right answer.

In my company that I employed with, we use Windows Server R2 Standard and it was live and functional.

Our team wants to upgrade to Windows R2 Enterprise

My question will the configuration in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio be lost if we upgrade the operating system?

These are the configurations in SQL Server

- Connections of the clients IP's
- API's
- Databases

Answer (score 0):

I just checking my question in here and I find it that I can answer this, for upgrading a windows server

```
1.API's will not  harm (because its a cloud base so no worries in here) nothing to do with the server upgrade.
2. Databases will not reset nor that it will increase the capacity of the storage.
3.clients IP's also under policies will not change.
```